# Manipulating TinyMCE content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

With TinyMCE, I can easily manipulate content and send it back to the editor, like this:

```
    // get content from tinyMCE
    var content = tinyMCE.get('content').getContent();

    // manipulate content using js replace
    content = content.replace(/<\/?div>/gi, '');

    // send back to tinyMCE
    tinyMCE.get('content').setContent( content );
```

The above code works fine. However, I can't get this to work:

```
    // get content from tinyMCE (it provides an html string)
    var content = tinyMCE.get('content').getContent();

    // make it into a jQuery object
    var $content = $(content);

    // manipulate the jquery object using jquery
    $content = $content.remove('a');

    // use a chained function to get its outerHTML
    content = $("<div />").append( $content.clone() ).html();               

    // send back to tinyMCE
    tinyMCE.get('content').setContent( content );
```

Is there something wrong with my methodology?

Comment: I notice that if I setContent in tinymce 4 <p> tags get wrapped around the content after I set it :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting and getting to TinyMCE was correct; the problem was with my use of `.remove()`:

```
$content = $content.remove('a');
```

Since the content from TinyMCE was a single object, and *not* a collection of objects some of which were `<a>` tags, that manipulation had no effect, and the html that returned was the same as the original.

In order to remove links, I instead needed this:

```
$content = $content.find('a').remove();
```

I received clarification in this thread: [Difference between $('#foo').remove('a') and $('#foo').find('a').remove()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860045/difference-between-foo-removea-and-foo-finda-remove)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the editor content using

```
var content = $('#content').html();
```

and set the content using

```
var content = $('#content').html('<span>NEW CONTENT</span>');
```

Comment: The problem is with the manipulation of the content, not the getting or setting.

Comment: you might try content.find('a').remove();

Comment: I think that works... why would .find('a').remove() work and .remove('a') wouldn't?