# Difference between $('#foo').remove('a') and $('#foo').find('a').remove()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to edit a string of HTML (from a textarea) using jQuery. When I use this code, links are removed from the resulting string, as expected:

```
      $('#foo').find('a').remove();
      $('#foo').html(); // links are removed, as expected
```

But when I use the code below, the links don't get removed.

```
      $('#foo').remove('a');
      $('#foo').html(); // links are still there
```

Why doesn't this work? I have read the jQuery API [documentation for .remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), and I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'a'` selector is a top level filter. It takes the current set, looks for elements that match the selector, and removes them.

```
$('#foo').remove('a');
```

The filter doesn't search nested elements.

So if you did this...

```
$('.myClass').remove('a');
```

...and the `.myClass` selector matched the following elements...

```
<p class="myClass">a paragraph</p>
<a class="myClass">an anchor</a>  <!-- will be removed -->
<p class="myClass">
    <a>a NESTED anchor</a>
</p>
<a class="myClass">an anchor</a>  <!-- will be removed -->
<a class="myClass">an anchor</a>  <!-- will be removed -->
<p class="myClass">
    <a>a NESTED anchor</a>
</p>
<p class="myClass">a paragraph</p>
```

...then only the `<a>` elements at the top level would be removed from the set

Answer (score 2):

`remove` operates on the set of elements *that you have already matched*, optionally filtering that set even further if you pass it an argument. So here's what each version does:

Find all the `<a>` descendants of `#foo` and remove them:

```
$('#foo').find('a').remove();
```

Find all the `<a>` elements that are in the set of `#foo` and remove them:

```
$('#foo').remove('a');
```

So this last one will do absolutely nothing if `#foo` is not an `<a>` itself; if it *is* (`<a id="foo">`) then this element will be removed. It's essentially the same as if you wrote

```
$('a#foo').remove();
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

difference is

```
$('#foo').remove('a');//This will help to get rid of <a /> in the dom structure.
$('#foo').remove();//This will remove the element with id foo
```

Comment: What do you mean by "filter `<a/>` out"? This syntax will actually remove any `<a>` elements within the initial jQuery object from the DOM.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, filter means it will get rid of the <a/> tag. Updated the description.

Comment: I believe that the first one will remove the element with id `foo` iff its element name is `a`.