# manipulating tinymce in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to be able to extract, manipulate and update the text in wordpress's tinymce #content textbox.The code is coded in a wordpress plugin.

The below post helps but i am unable to comment or contact the original creator to ask him further questions. Having 1 points I cant practically do anything except ask questions. Let me know if i am doing this wrong.

Basically the code from this link is what i need to manipulate or edit the content in wordpress tinymce editor.
[Manipulating TinyMCE content with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828418/manipulating-tinymce-content-with-jquery)

But the code seems to be overly simplified.

so my question is:

Do i need to include jquery

Do i need to include the tinymce js or class? is it in wordpress itself?

The code seems to be half javascript half php? Is the code suppose to be coded in a .js file?

do i need to put php tags here?

```
    // make it into a jQuery object
    var $content = $(content);

    // manipulate the jquery object using jquery
    $content = $content.remove('a');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually have tinymce up and running in wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi I have figured it out after a bit more researching.

At first I was working with php to manipulate data after it is saved. But then i went on to wanting to manipulate the text before it was saved like underlining certain text based on a list in the database. So I needed to move on to javascript because i was editing the text before it was submitted or a page reload which i didn't wrap my head around yet.

So next i just coded the changes into javascript and built a button to call the process.

and seems i didn't need to include the tinymce class because probably the header of the editor page has already included it.